# Generated macro names in files generated with docstrip

Tags: dtx

I started using `DocStrip` and `Doc`.  I already managed to use different guards or modules, to create different package files from one single `.dtx`-source and I am happy with that.

I am wondering, if it would be possible, to automatically integrate the module name into macro names?

For example, lets imagine, my `foobar.ins` file looks like this:

```tex
\input docstrip.tex

\generate{\file{foo.sty}{\from{foobar.dtx}{foo}}}
\generate{\file{bar.sty}{\from{foobar.dtx}{bar}}}
```

Further, lets suppose, my `foobar.dtx` file has some code like this:

```tex
% \begin{macro}{\ifmy@foo@baz}
% \begin{macro}{\ifmy@bar@baz}
% This boolean switch is used to activate special baz options.
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<foo>\ifmy@foo@baz
%<bar>\ifmy@bar@baz
%    \end{macrocode}
```

This works, no question.  It would on the other hand, be much more elegant to set up the macro name automatically and being dependent on the guard/modulename which is used in the `.ins` file.  When I run `tex foobar.ins` and look afterwards in the freshly created `foo.sty` file, I find at the top of the file something like `This is file foo.sty, ... with option 'foo'.`  Docstrip is of course able to insert the actual option name into the file, it is creating (at least as comment).

Something like this would be nice:

```tex
%    \begin{macrocode}
\ifmy@\actualoption@baz
%    \end{macrocode}
```

as it would then be sufficient, to use only one line to generate all desired variants.

Comment: the l3 version of this (`l3doc`) has `%<@@=⟨module ⟩>` for exactly this use you could back port some of that logic to doc probably

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you.  This adds `__` in Front of the module name but this seems to be the new future?  Anyways, I think, this should do the trick.  Thank you, David!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle having updated my TeXLive, I think, l3doc has made it into the final state.  At least the file `docstrip.pdf` now lists also this `%<@@=module>` feature.